# out of memory error while concatenating multiple CSV

Tags: python-3.x

My question is about how to resolve memory error in python

I am working with about multiple csv files and trying to concatenate them all together. While doing that, I am facing an error "error tokenizing data. C error: out of memory"

1 csv file is having rows of about 20478 and 8 column. And there are 2155 of such files.

The Data is huge.

How to solve this error?

Comment: we don't even how exactly you're concatenating them :SMH:

Comment: at least provide your current code snippet!

Comment: Concat them using shell cmds and the load in chunks (provided they all have same column names in same order) or you can also use memory_map as well etc..